# Kendo UI grid paging: 'Items per page' selection doesn't work

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, pagination, kendo-grid

I am having paging issues with the Kendo UI grid. The drop down for number of items to display per page will not allow me to select any of it's options. Clicking them does nothing. It won't even change the value in the select box. It's as if they are disabled (but they aren't).

Here is my code:

```
/***** Data Source *****/
dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: spec.urlRead,
            type: 'json'
        },
        create: {
            url: spec.urlCreate,
            type: 'post'
        },
        update: {
            url: spec.urlUpdate,
            type: 'post'
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: 'Code',
            fields: {
                Name: { type: 'string' },
                Description: { type: 'string' }
            }
        }
    }
});

/***** Grid *****/
$(spec.gridSelector).kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { title: spec.fieldTitles.Name, field: 'Name', width: 200 },
        { title: spec.fieldTitles.Description, field: 'Description'}
    ],
    dataSource: dataSource,
    filterable: true,
    height: 250,
    pageable: {
        buttonCount: 3,
        pageSize: 10,
        pageSizes: [5,10,20],
        refresh: true,
        serverPaging: false
    },
    scrollable: true,
    sortable: true
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:** I realized that I was using Kendo v2012.2.913. After updating to v2013.2.918, the problem fixed itself.

Comment: Don't see any problems and your pageable settings work fine. Can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: This could be an issue with some other element or CSS conflicting with the grid page dropdown.

Comment: _pageable_ of **Kendo Grid** has no property called _serverPaging_, remove `serverPaging: false`. The _serverPaging_ is one of **Kendo DataSource** configurations and default value of it is _false_ so you don't need set it too.

Comment: I'm thinking that @jwatts1980 is right about outside influences in my app. That being said, I realized I was on a really old (early 2012) version of kendo. After updating, this issue seemed to have resolved itself.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @ImanMahmoudinasab. That was left over from my attempts to fix another issue.